Ошибка кода со встроенной функцией Python - int()
Взял из учебника пример:
def even_odd():
n = input("Enter number: ")
n = int(n)
if n % 2 == 0:
    print(" n is even ")
else:
     print(" n is odd ")
even_odd()
even_odd()
even_odd()

Пробовал запустить этот код в PowerShall.
Не работает, указывает на ошибку.
В чем моя ошибка?

Первая ошибка - отсутствие самой ошибки в вопросе. Вторая, возможная, нет отступов после определения функции

В "PowerShall"? Powershell - это другая опера.

@SwaD, я скорее за вариант Fox'а, а сдвиг поменялся при написании вопроса.

def even_odd():
    n = input("Enter number: ")
    n = int(n)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print("n is even")
    else:
        print("n is odd")

even_odd()
even_odd()
even_odd()

У Вас проблемы с табуляцией, дело в том, что питон не понял что находится внутри функции even_odd

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
